# IntelliJ Idea JDK path

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have ubuntu 14.04, Im trying to configure IntelliJ Idea with scala, but I have problem with JDK path.
This is my configuration:
[image: My configuration]
What Im doing wrong?

Comment: May permission issue for that directory

Comment: What are the contents of that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I installed openjdk again as I saw some less files there.

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the given path is pointing to **JDK**, not only to **JRE**.